# Search results - first PHP, then JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make my search function on my site a bit simpler:

Library: single function to call and filter results.
Controller: Currently two functions, one for the initial PHP load of the results, the other to replace the results div of the search page.

In this case, I have two Views doing almost the exact same thing, which makes the code a bit redundant.

The first view, associated with the first controller, loads all elements of the page + the results div.
The second view, which just updates the results div, only contains HTML related to the results div.

When a user updates a search filter, an AJAX call calls the second controller and replaces the initial view with the second view.

How can I move to just one view?

Controllers:

```
public function display($criteria = null)
{
    // create an instance of the view
    $this->template->content = View::instance('v_results_display');

    // name the page
    $this->template->title = "Search Results";

    //$filtered_results->teacher_results = $this->teachers->filter_teachers(array('criteria' => $_POST['criteria'], 'countries' => $_POST['filters']['countries'], 'stations' => $_POST['filters']['stations'], 'min' => $_POST['min'], 'max' => $_POST['max']));

    if($_POST['criteria'])
    {
        $criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
    }

    # SEARCH BY GROUP
    // allow search by group
    // i.e. if someone searches for math, it should bring up all teachers who teach any kind of math

        switch($criteria)
        {
            case ("math"):
            case ("science"):
            case ("language"):
            case ("college prep"):
            case ("test prep"):
            case ("english"):
            case ("other"):
                $criterions = $this->subjects->get_subjects_return_implode($criteria);
                break;
            default:
                $criterions = $criteria;
                break;
        }

    if($_GET['page'])
    {
        if(is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
            $pageNum = intval($_GET['page']);
            if($pageNum == 0)
            {
                $pageNum = null;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $pageNum = null;
        }

    }

    // call library function for searching
    // maintaining the integrity of the group search
    //$teacher_results = $this->teachers->search_teachers_with_or_without_criteria($criterions, $pageNum);

    //$filtered_results->teacher_results = $this->teachers->filter_teachers(array('criteria' => $_POST['criteria'], 'countries' => $_POST['filters']['countries'], 'stations' => $_POST['filters']['stations'], 'min' => $_POST['min'], 'max' => $_POST['max']));


    $teacher_results = $this->teachers->filter_teachers(array('criteria' => $criterions));

    $teacher_results = $this->teachers->filter_teachers(array('criteria' => $criterions, 'countries' => $_POST['filters']['countries'], 'stations' => $_POST['filters']['stations'], 'min' => $_POST['min'], 'max' => $_POST['max']));

    // a non limited count of all the results, regardless of what page they appear on
    // the previous query has a LIMIT in the SQL, so it can't offer a total count of all teachers
    // across all pages
    $this->template->content->totalResultsCount = count($this->teachers->get_teachers());

    $like_dislike = new Teachers();
    $this->template->content->like_dislike = $like_dislike;

    // pass to view accessible variable
    $this->template->content->teacher_results = $teacher_results;

    // pass criteria variable to be used in view
    // this will probably only be used to echo out to the user what is going on
    $this->template->content->criteria = $criteria;

    // get teacher count for all pages
    $this->template->content->unlimitedTeacherCount = $this->teachers->CountTeachersAllPages($criterions);

    // for the hidden div, which helps with the filtering
    $this->template->content->criterions = $criterions;

    $app_form = new App_Form();
    $this->template->content->app_form = $app_form;

    $app_user_var = new App_User();
    $this->template->content->app_user_var = $app_user_var;

    # CSS/JS includes

    $client_files_head = Array(
        '/css/results.css',
        '/css/mobile_results.css',
        "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"

    );

    $client_files_body = Array(
        '/js/results.js',
        '/js/jquery.browser.min.js',
        'http://libs.baidu.com/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js'
    );

    // load CSS/JS files
    $this->template->client_files_body = Utils::load_client_files($client_files_body);
    $this->template->client_files_head = Utils::load_client_files($client_files_head);

    // render template
    echo $this->template;

}

// may have gotten rid of the need for this guy
public function search_filter() {

    // create an instance of the view
    $filtered_results = View::instance('v_results_search_filter');

    // return teachers sought
    $filtered_results->teacher_results = $this->teachers->filter_teachers(array('criteria' => $_POST['criteria'], 'countries' => $_POST['filters']['countries'], 'stations' => $_POST['filters']['stations'], 'min' => $_POST['min'], 'max' => $_POST['max']));

    $client_files_head = Array (
       '/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css',
       '/css/results.css'
    );

    // so that our country prefixes are defined correctly
    $client_files_body = Array(
        '/js/bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.js'
    );

    // load CSS/JS files
    $filtered_results->client_files_head = Utils::load_client_files($client_files_head);
    $filtered_results->client_files_body = Utils::load_client_files($client_files_body);

    $app_user_var = new App_User();
    $filtered_results->app_user_var = $app_user_var;

    // make filtered results available to page
    $filtered_results->filters = $_POST['filters'];

    // for the ratings
    $like_dislike = new Teachers();
    $filtered_results->like_dislike = $like_dislike;

    // make min and max pay available to page
    $filtered_results->min = $_POST['min'];
    $filtered_results->max = $_POST['max'];

    $filtered_results->post = $_POST;

    // send response back to AJAX
    echo $filtered_results;

}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include your code?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to make very detailed remarks, but you could use a single route and controller by looking for a query param to pick which variant is needed for the request. Your urls might look like:

```
GET /path/to/search?q=potatoes
```

for the initial load vs

```
GET /path/to/search?q=potatoes&partial=true
```

for the AJAX.

Both these requests would hit the same route and controller (*pseudocode follows!*)

```
route("/path/to/search", mySearchController)

function mySearchController(args) {
    result = do_some_query(args)
    if ('partial' in queryparams) {
        do_partial_render(result)
    } else {
        do_full_render(result)
    }
}
```

The partial/full render situation would involve template inheritance

full.template:

```
<? include 'header' ?>
<h1>My Nice Search</h1>
<? include 'results_table' ?>
<? include 'footer' ?>
```

results_table.template

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{result}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is a pretty general answer to a pretty general question, the pseudocode is meant to be schematic only.